# Term shorter than "microblog" as generic equivalent of "tweet"

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, technology

I *search* rather than *Google* and *vacuum* rather than *Hoover*. Technically I *microblog* rather than *tweet*, but it just doesn't sound as snappy. Is there a short (single syllable?), established, generic term I can use in case I switch to identi.ca?

Comment: I had this issue for a very long time. Firstly I feel it is wrong to brand *tweet* as *microblog*. I feel it was more a convenience, during the initial stages of Twitter, to relate these short messages with something popular, and hence got associated with blogging. My personal opinion is that both *tweet* and *blog* serve different purposes, and should be taken differently. Hence I would not use *microblog* for *tweet* and vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ***microblog***.

Here are the various verbs out there that Twitter competitors and users are actually using and therefore would be meaningful.

- Identi.ca – *microblog*
- Jaiku (defunct) – "share updates" and "share short messages"
- Sprout – *microblog*
- Plurk – *plurk*
- Pownce (defunct) – "send stuff"
- Tumblr - *microblog*
- Yammer – *microblog*

I conclude that *microblog* is the accepted term in circulation that means *publish via a short message service*. The only shorter, snappier terms are vendor specific.

Answer (score 3):

*Microblog* is the only verb that refers specifically to short public postings to social networking services like Twitter.  However, in many contexts *post* and *update*, while more generic, will do.

For example,

> “She wastes all of her time *microblogging* on Twitter.”

can be replaced with

> “She wastes all of here time *posting* to Twitter.”

*Post* and *update* also apply in social networking contexts where *microblog* doesn't make sense. One does not *microblog* on Facebook, but one does *post* to Facebook.

Comment: I agree that "post" is a better short term.

Answer (score 3):

Just a historical note on what is an old question that has burbled back into activity.

My understanding was that "tumblelog" was the original term for posting short messages on a social media platform. [Kottke.org](http://www.kottke.org/05/10/tumblelogs) has a nice definition from 2005: "A tumblelog is a quick and dirty stream of consciousness, a bit like a remaindered links style linklog but with more than just links." The same post also uses it as a verb ("tumblelogging"). This is also where the "Tumblr" name came from.

However, as this [TechTarget definition](http://searchcio-midmarket.techtarget.com/definition/tumblelog) suggests, "microblog/ging" is now the more common term.

FWIW. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*[Zing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zing)*, a verb meaning "To move very quickly, especially while making a high-pitched hum", might adapt to your purpose.  Its major drawback is its variegated [previous use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zing).

An apposite choice is *[blat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blat)*, a verb meaning "To cry, as a calf or sheep; to bleat; to make a senseless noise; to talk inconsiderately" and "To produce an overrich or overblown sound on a brass instrument such as a trumpet, trombone, or tuba".  However, acceptance could be slow because some may see it as pejorative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how widely used the term is (so I won't set this as an answer -- yet), but the Free Software Foundation use *chirp* as an alternative:

> Chirp along with us on your microblogging service of choice

From [FSF blog post of the same name](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/community/chirp-along-with-us-on-your-microblogging-service-of-choice).

Answer (score 0):

Mastodon is a federated microblogging platform that allows communities to pick their own terminology. [The default term used by Mastodon platform is *toot*.](https://github.com/tootsuite/documentation/blob/master/Using-Mastodon/FAQ.md) A default term is not quite the same as a generic term, but to my knowledge *toot* is not intended to have and has not yet acquired the meaning "microblogging specifically via Mastodon".