# "Brief" and "complete" — need an intermediate between them

Tags: single-word-requests, degree-of-comparison

Let's say you have some ideas and are going to share them on the Internet. You have a Twitter account, a blog and an ability to publish your thoughts in a magazine. You're writing three articles, all containing exactly the same information, but these articles differ in their level of detail:

1. The first is the shortest one, it's for Twitter. There are no details, so I'd call it a pretty **brief** article.
2. The second one is for your blog, it's several times longer.
3. And then the third one is pretty large, a couple of pages probably. It's well-detailed, so I'd call it a **complete** article.

So, the question is — what's the right word for the case 2?

Any other three words to reflect these differences also will do (these should be *single words*, not phrases).

Comment: You'd always better wait a couple of days before you accept an answer. You can up vote answers you find suitable in the meanwhile.

Comment: Related: _[Term shorter than “microblog” as generic equivalent of “tweet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/55906/5822)_

Comment: Why not _tweet_, _blog_, _article_?

Comment: I'm with @Callithumpian on this one. Something squeezed into 140 characters is not an *article*. It's not even a *brief version* or an *abstract*. It's just a tweet.

Comment: For the latter two, *abridged* and *unabridged* come to mind. (That's the term Audible.com uses for indicating that one recording is not a full version of another.) Then I'd use *tweet* for the first one, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brief; short; full.

As in:
Select a version to view:
brief — short — full

Comment: How is brief different from short in this context?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider 1) Outline/Synopsis/Brief 2) Detailed 3) Extensive/Complete

Answer (score 2):

Also try "summary" as in an executive summary, which is the office-world version of the kind/length of document you are describing. A "one-sheet" is the term used in the music/entertainment biz.